# NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey() returns compile error

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I want to check if the NSUserDefaults has the value with the key of `dic`, then load the data and save into `loadedDic` if the data exist, or set the value of `loadedDic` and save into `NSUserDefaults` if not.

The statement commented with `error!` returns an error message:

> cannot assign value of type `[String : AnyObject]?` to `[String : [String]]`

I thought it would be okay because the return type of the method `dictionaryForKey` says `AnyObject`. Still don't fully understand this AnyObject type :(

Can anyone explain to me what makes the error and how I should take care of this problem? Thanks in advance.

The following code block is in `viewDidLoad()` method in a `UIViewController` class.

```
var loadedDic = [String : [String]]()

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

if defaults.dictionaryForKey("dic") != nil {
  print("there's the value i want")
  loadedDic = defaults.dictionaryForKey("dic")//error!
}else {
  //some codes to set values of 'loadedDic'. this part works properly

  defaults.setObject(loadedDic, forKey: "dic")
  if defaults.synchronize(){
    print("saved")
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `.synchronize()`, this is obsolete. Defaults are already saved as soon as you do `.setObject`.

Comment: Defaults are not saved as soon as `.setObject` is called. See doc here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize

Answer (score 1):

Check type of the dictionary received from `NSUserDefaults` is expected type:

```
if defaults.dictionaryForKey("dic") != nil {
    print("there's the value i want")
    if let dic = defaults.dictionaryForKey("dic") as? [String : [String]]{
       loadedDic = dic
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't even need first `if` here

Answer (score 0):

try

```
     var loadedDic = [String : AnyObject]()
```

instead of

```
  var loadedDic = [String : [String]]()
```

Comment: this one doesn't work. the error message says quite the same as the message in the question; "cannot assign value of type [String : AnyObject]? to [String : [AnyObject]]". note that the value is an array of String.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do it like this way.

```
var loadedDic = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
```

Now, at the time of fetching dictionary from NSUserDefault

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

if let dic : Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = defaults.dictionaryForKey("dic") as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
{
    loadedDic = defaults.dictionaryForKey("dic")
}
else
{
    //some codes to set values of 'loadedDic'. this part works properly
    // Make sure you store it in Dictionary<String, AnyObject>() manner

    defaults.setObject(loadedDic, forKey: "dic")
    if defaults.synchronize(){
        print("saved")
    }
}
```